# Can't get the input from my HTML form in my python flask app

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to linkind html text boxes with my python flask app so that I can interact with it, so I tried a lot of things and "parse" the internet to look how to do it, but nothing did work.

However, I did a little small test program so that you can understand better, and I'm still going in lot of errors, actually the page test launch itself, and after enterring my input and pressing the submit button, I have a an "Method Not Allowed" error, though I thought it'll fixed itself if in methods field I put "get" and "POST" methods both.

Anyway I'm actually blocked and I need you to help me making this simple program work.

Here is the route for my program :

```
@app.route('/test.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def route_test():
    text = request.form.get('text')
    print(text)
    return render_template('test.html', message = text)
```

And here the html page linked to it :

```
<!doctype html> <html lang= "en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Indiquer votre nom</h1> <form action= "." method= "POST">
<input type= "text" name= "text"> <button type= "submit">OK</button>
</form>
<p>{{ message }}</p>
</body> </html>
```

As you can see It is super simple, though It won't print me the text whatsoever.

I also did try with request.form['text'], and changing the `action="."` with different things, but nothing did change. Hope you'll solve my problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm back, I finally did find an answer, that I'll post here for those who are interested:
In fact you have to create an other route which link (URL) will be the action of your html form so that you have your static page that when pressing submit button call an other route that is a function in python, and then you can get your outputs with request.form['input1'].

Anyway, here's a little code example:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def route_test():
    text = request.form.get('text')
    print(text)
    return render_template('test.html', message = text)

@app.route('/test_obtain_input', methods=['POST'])
def route_test_obtain_input():
    text = request.form['text']
    print(text)
##you can do whatever you want with it after, here I just reinjecting it in my test page
    return render_template('test.html', message = text)
```

And so my HTML form would be like :

```
<!-- insert the url that is adequate to your application -->
<form action= "https://localhost:5000/test_obtain_input" method= "POST">
<input type= "text" name= "text">
<button type= "submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

Though I did not test this code because I used this on my real page, It should work, and it is the good logic whatsoever, my teammate and me didn't find any other solution to do so.